# How to compile a program with limit time (5s), using MinGW-Gnu C++

Tags: c++, g++, gnu-make, gnu

I knew how to compile a program with GNU, but some program can be in "Infinity Loop". The goal is to avoid frustration when there is an infinite loop in the program by automatically killing it after some given time interval, called "Time litmit". **How to using GNU Makefile to do it ?**

> Example : Compile & running this code in 1s with n=10^10
>
> ```
> int main()
> {
>     int n =10000000000;
>     vector<int> a;
>     for (int i=0;i<n)
>         a.push(i);
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> If program running over 1s, it's must be **killed** and i need a
>   **"Time limited exceeded" notify**.

Sorry for bad English :)

Comment: That's something to do in your code, not with compiler options.

Comment: You can spawn the process in the background, then run a timer in the shell and kill the process if it has not completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using shell with a sequence like

```
<program>& 
pid=$!
sleep $time_limit
if ps aux | grep $pid | grep -v grep > /dev/null
then 
  kill $pid
  echo "Time limit exceeded"
fi
```

Here are two examples with and without reaching the time limit (using `sleep 10` and `sleep 3` as program, with a time limit of 5 seconds):

```
$ sleep 10& pid=$!; sleep 5; if ps aux | grep $pid | grep -v grep > /dev/null; then kill $pid; echo "Time limit exceeded"; fi
Time limit exceeded
$ sleep 3& pid=$!; sleep 5; if ps aux | grep $pid | grep -v grep > /dev/null; then kill $pid; echo "Time limit exceeded"; fi
$
```

The way it works is that the program is launched in background (with the `&` after the program name). The pid (`$!`) is stored in a variable named `pid`. Then I wait `$time_limit` using sleep and I check if the process with pid `$pid` still runs. I use `| grep -v grep` because the `grep $pid` will also appear in the output of `ps aux`.

If the process still runs, I kill it and display the message you wanted.

This can be included easily in a Makefile. You could also make it a shell script in your `PATH` if you want to be able to use it in other context.

Answer (score 0):

When your program hangs, use ^C to interrupt it. Then, go into your code and find the problem. Use a debugger like GDB to step through your code and find the infinite loop. I'm not sure what the point of auto-terminating the program would be, other than allowing you to run it multiple times despite the fact that it's broken. Is it generating some kind of meaningful output that you need, and you are just unwilling to find the bug?